# json ошибка ncaught SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, json

Не могу получить значение. data4.users.User1, пишет ошибку

```
let json4 ='{"users":{"User1":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}},{"User2":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}}';

let data4 = JSON.parse(json4);
console.log(data4.users.User1);
```

Comment: У Вас не валидный JSON. По идее должно быть `'{"users":{"User1":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},"User2":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}}'`.

Comment: Всё работает, спасибо можете оформить, как ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Невалидный Json. Сделайте его валидным.

Для начала закиньте своё произведение искусства в какой-либо онлнайн парсер, например https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/# и посмотрите что не так. Затем исправьте, чтобы был валидным

---

А вместо того, чтобы сразу писать json в одну строку - проще вначале сформировать нужный объект, а потом сделать `JSON.stringify`. Тогда и JSON будет валидным

```js
let test = {
  user: 123,
  name: 'haha',
  what: {
        some: 234,
        hi: 'hi'
    }
}


testString = JSON.stringify(test);
console.log(testString);
```

Если на стороне сервера, например *PHP*, то формирование json делается через [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста, у меня где ошибка в коде

Comment: @Ivan912 вы что, на каждый чихпых будете бежать на SO чтоб другие смотрели ваши невалидные строки? Нет уж. Сами исправьте. Как - см. ответ выше

Answer (score -2):

У Вас не валидный JSON. Должно быть:

```js
let json4 ='{"users":{"User1":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"},"User2":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}}}';

let data4 = JSON.parse(json4);
console.log(data4.users.User1);
```

Comment: обосную минус: это даёт понимание автору, что каждый раз при кривых ручёнках будет бежать на SO вместо того, чтобы уметь самому нормально разобраться в проблеме и сформировать корректно всё.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо что оставили комментарий с обоснованием

Comment: @АлексейШиманский по мне: надо просто закрывать вопрос. Причина хорошо описана - проблема не воспроизводима: опечатки и так далее. Почему прямой ответ на прямой вопрос должен минусоваться...

Comment: @Leonid да ради бога. У вас такое мнение - пожалуйста